# How do i capture events onClick of a google maps fusion table layer..?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hmmm.. I have a map with several points on it. And I'd like to get the latitude and longitude when a point is clicked. How do I do that?

ps. I'm quite new to javascript, so
an example would really help.. T_T

There is something about it in the docs,
I just have no idea how to use it because of my noobness to javascript..
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#FusionTablesMouseEvent

```
 function initPoints()
{
    points = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: "points",
        from: poleid
        },
    styles: [{
        markerOptions: {
        iconName: "small_green"
        }
        }],

    suppressInfoWindows: true
    }); 


    points.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it..

```
google.maps.event.addListener(points, 'click', function(event) {

        alert("lat:"+ event.latLng.lat());

        });
```